# ElasticSearch: Sorting a complex query

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested

I have a complex query in Elasticsearch (below) and I need to sort by date_creation ascending, within the "Activité" (activity) bucket. The query works, but the basic sort I have for date_creation does not.  I am looking for how I would sort the Activities by date_creation, in ascending order. I've seen some posts on nested queries [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569898/elasticsearch-nested-sorting), for example and [here in the elastic search documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html) but they don't seem to answer how to address the complexity of my query.

I am using ElasticSearch 2.3.5 with Lucene 5.5.0.

```
var searchQuery = {
  index: "resultats_" + env,
  body: {
    size: 0,
    sort: [{ date_creation: { order: "asc", mode: "min" } }],
    query: {
      filtered: {
        query: {
          match_all: {}
        },
        filter: {
          query: {
            bool: {
              should: [{}],
              must: [
                {
                  term: {
                    player_id: {
                      value: params.player_id
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  term: {
                    classes: {
                      value: params.grade
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              must_not: [{}]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    aggs: {
      Matière: {
        terms: {
          field: "id_matiere",
          size: 10
        },
        aggs: {
          "Titre matière": {
            top_hits: {
              _source: {
                include: ["titre_matiere"]
              },
              size: 1
            }
          },
          PP: {
            terms: {
              field: "id_point_pedago",
              size: 10
            },
            aggs: {
              "Titre PP": {
                top_hits: {
                  _source: {
                    include: ["titre_point_pedago"]
                  },
                  size: 1
                }
              },
              Compétence: {
                terms: {
                  field: "id_competence",
                  size: 10
                },
                aggs: {
                  "Titre compétence": {
                    top_hits: {
                      _source: {
                        include: ["titre_competence"]
                      },
                      size: 1
                    }
                  },
                  Activité: {
                    terms: {
                      field: "id_activite",
                      size: 10
                    },
                    aggs: {
                      "Titre activité": {
                        top_hits: {
                          _source: {
                            include: [
                              "titre_activite",
                              "nombre_perimetre_occurrence"
                            ]
                          },
                          size: 1
                        }
                      },
                      Trimestres: {
                        filters: {
                          filters: {
                            T1: {
                              range: {
                                date_creation: {
                                  gte: params.t1_start,
                                  lte: params.t1_end
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            T2: {
                              range: {
                                date_creation: {
                                  gte: params.t2_start, 
                                  lte: params.t2_end 
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            T3: {
                              range: {
                                date_creation: {
                                  gte: params.t3_start, 
                                  lte: params.t3_end
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        aggs: {
                          Moyenne: {
                            avg: {
                              field: "resultat"
                            }
                          },
                          Occurrences: {
                            cardinality: {
                              field: "id_occurrence",
                              precision_threshold: 1000
                            }
                          },
                          Résultat: {
                            terms: {
                              field: "resultat",
                              size: 10,
                              min_doc_count: 0
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: So you want to sort the top hits under the `Activité` aggregation?

Comment: Yes, @Val that sounds about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
              Activité: {
                terms: {
                  field: "id_activite",
                  size: 10
                },
                aggs: {
                  "Titre activité": {
                    top_hits: {
                      _source: {
                        include: [
                          "titre_activite",
                          "nombre_perimetre_occurrence"
                        ]
                      },
                      size: 1,
add this line ->      sort: [{ date_creation: { order: "asc", mode: "min" } }],
                    }
                  },
```

Comment: I can't confirm that it's working, yet, but I can confirm that it's not breaking my query - and your answer helps me get the general idea.