# NestedSortBuilder usage example for elasticsearch 6.3.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-nested

I have to sort on a field that is one level nested using the elastic java high level rest client api. I could find this answer

[Elasticsearch nested sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569898/elasticsearch-nested-sorting)

The problem is that the answer uses SortBuilder for sorting nested fields using the following code :

```
SortBuilder sb = SortBuilders.fieldSort("authorList.lastName")
    .order(SortOrder.ASC)
    .setNestedPath("authorList")
    .setNestedFilter(matchFirst);
```

However it seems that nestedPath and NestedFilter have been deprecated in 6.3.2  elastic ([deprication info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html))and a new NestedSortBuilder has been introduced. However I was not able to build a query using it. Can anyone please explain how to use it or perhaps point me to an example where it has been used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually was easy. This works for me :

```
SortBuilders.fieldSort("bulkOrders.expiryDate").order(SortOrder.asc).setNestedSort(new NestedSortBuilder("bulkOrders"));
```

This is equivalent to :

```
"sort": [
        {
          "bulkOrders.expiryDate": {
            "order": "asc",
            "nested": {
              "path": "bulkOrders"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```